# Cardinality of the set $\{(-1,..,-1,1,...,1,-1,...-1): \text{ arbitrary patterns but where 1s are never separate}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, optimization

I have always struggled with combinatorics, and I am attempting to calculate the cardinality of the set $\{(-1,..,-1,1,...,1,-1,...-1)\in \mathbb R^{n}: \text{ arbitrary patterns but where 1s are  never separate}\}$.

My attempt: Let $a=\text{ number of 1s}$

In case:

$a=0\implies \text{ one configuration }(-1,...,-1)$

$a=1\implies \text{ n configurations }(1,-1,...,-1),...,(-1,...,-1,1)$

$a=2\implies \text{ n-1 configurations }(1,1,-1,...,-1),...,(-1,...,-1,1,1)$

...

$a=k>0\implies \text{ n+1-k configurations }$

So I would guess that the cardinality of the set would be:

$1+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}(n+1-k)=1+n(n+1)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k=1+n(n+1)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}k=1+n(n+1)-n(n+1)/2\\=1+n(n+1)/2$

Is this correct? Even if it is, I would be interested in learning perhaps more efficient/effective ways of calculating the cardinality of sets. Thanks!

Comment: Your answer is correct. Note that the number of configurations with two or more $1$s is $\binom n2=C(n,2)=n(n-1)/2$. because the whole configuration is determined by the position of the first $1$ and the last $1$, and $\binom n2$ is the number of combinations of $2$ things from $n$. To that you have to add $n+1$, the number of configurations with one $1$ or no $1$s.

Comment: You can also think of it like a [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem. Here you choose 2 of the n+1 spots to place the bars (the n-1 spaces between the numbers and the 2 ends), and all the numbers between the bars are the 1s. Then add the case with no 1s at all to get $\binom{n+1}2 + 1$.